# how could an int be extracted from a line of text?

Tags: c#, string

I have hit a snag in some data parsing because the title line of what I am parsing is somewhat complex. It has the year, the title, and the edition, but not always in that order. the year and the edition can be converted to ints but the rest cannot be. how could I split the year from the rest of the line to be parsed to an int if I don't know where it would be in the line every time?

example data sets:

2016 Super special regular season, 01 fifteenth tossup

Math problems galore 2013 Round 02 directed problems

FooBar the amazing game part 1 0f 2 round 03 problems 2015

I know that I can't just test the whole line to see if a character is a number, because there are multiple numbers. Nor can I do something like IndexOf because of not knowing the dates ahead of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To get all numbers from string use the regex.Matches() method to get
>   all matches from the regex

```
     /* \d+ Is used to find integers */
     Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+"); 

     // Loop thrue all matches 
     foreach (Match match in regex.Matches("2016 Super special regular season, 01 fifteenth tossup"))
     {
         Console.WriteLine(match.Value); /* Test output */
         int i = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value); /* Convert To Int and do something with it */
     }

      ============ output ===========
      2016
      01


     /* Use this \d{4} to return the 4 character from current match from \d*/
     /* (Example) => 12564568 => (output) : 1256 and 4568 */
     /* (Notice!!) If you use \d{4} and there are only 2 numbers found by \d
        It has no result. */
```

> Or in one line to get the result value from the first occurring number:

```
    string resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString /*string to test */, @"\d+").Value;
```

Comment: This answers the question in the title but seems to ignore the question body.

Comment: I've updated it the top one describes exactly what he asked It gets every single number from the string and converts it to an integer.

Comment: That is a very good explanation. Only improvement could be made in terms of this for regular expression. `\d{4}`. This will only return an integer with four characters.

Answer (score 3):

Use Regex :

```
    string pattern_Year = @"\(\d{4}\)";
    string pattern_Edition = @"\(\d{2}\)";
    string search = "2016 Super special regular season, 01 fifteenth tossup";
    var year = Regex.Matches(search, pattern_Year );
    var edition = Regex.Matches(search, pattern_Edition );
    if(year.Count > 0)
      Console.WriteLine(year[0].Value);
    if(edition.Count > 0)
      Console.WriteLine(edition [0].Value);
```

Comment: could you please explain what your regular expression pattern does? I don't really use it often and can't remember what the symbols in the pattern do

Comment: string pattern_Year = @"\(\d{4}\)", it's simple find the number have 4 digit as year.

Answer (score 1):

```
var line = "FooBar the amazing game part 1 0f 2 round 03 problems 2015";

var numbers = line.Split(' ').Where(word => word.All(char.IsDigit)).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Now you have the ints 1, 2, 3, 2015.

How you find out what the year is is up to you. Maybe check which is between 1900 and 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    static int GetYearFromTextLine(string s)
    {
        string [] words = s.Split(' ');

        foreach (string w in words)
        {
            int number = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(w, out number))
            {
                // assume the first number found over "1900" must be a year
                // you can modify this test yourself
                if (number >= 1900)
                {
                    return number;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetYearFromTextLine("Math problems galore 2013 Round 02 directed problems"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, should work

```
    string strValue = "abc123def456";
    char[] charArr = strValue.ToCharrArray();
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
   for(int i =0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
      {
         string tmpInt ="";
         if(char.IsDigit(charArr[i]))
           {
            tmpInt += charArr[i];
             while((i < charArr.Lenght -1 ) && char.IsDigit([i + 1)
                 {
                   tmpInt += charArr[i+1];
                   i++;
                 }
           }
          if(tmpInt != "")
          intList.Add(int.Parse(tmpInt));
      }
```

Advantage of this script is, does not matter where digits located in the string and not depended on split or any pattern.